# What is a frenzy charge?

Tags: path-of-exile

I noticed some passive skills that mention Frenzy Charges, either increasing the amount you get by one or having some other effects.

What is a Frenzy Charge? How do I get them in the first place? What do they do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. What's a (frenzy) charge ?**

> Charges are glowing orbs that represent temporary amplification of
>   physical and mental abilities. There are three types of charges, each
>   corresponding to a different core attribute:
>
> - Endurance charges are associated with strength.
> - **Frenzy charges are associated with dexterity.**
> - Power charges are associated with intelligence.

**2. How to get charges ?**

> Charges are accumulated by the use of certain skills and equipment,
>   and last a short duration—nine seconds by default. Gaining a charge
>   resets the duration of all accumulated charges.

**3. What do they do ?**

> Each type of charge grants different bonuses. A charge bonus increases
>   proportional to the number of accumulated charges of that type.
>
> By default, characters can have a maximum of three charges of each type active. This limit can be raised by certain passives and equipment.

More specifically, in the case of frenzy charges:

> Frenzy charges are associated with dexterity and represent a temporary
>   increase to swiftness and fervor during combat. They are visualized as
>   glowing green orbs surrounding the character. Bonuses granted by
>   frenzy charges:
>
> - +5% increased Attack Speed per Charge
> - +5% increased Cast Speed per Charge

Sources:

- http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Charge
- http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Frenzy_Charge

[image: Frenzy charges]

Comment: `Each type of charge grants different bonuses.` That still doesn't really answer the question of what they do.

Comment: Do you have any more specifics on how to get them? `Certain skills and equipment` is also quite vague.

Comment: The list is a bit long; it's explained in full details on [the wiki page given above](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Frenzy_Charge) ;)